# How to use Jackson JsonSubTypes annotation in Kotlin

Tags: jackson, kotlin

I'm trying to convert some Java code that uses Jackson's @JsonSubTypes annotation to manage polymorphism.

Here is the working Java code:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(
    use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
    include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY,
    property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes({
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Comment.class, name = "CommentNote"),
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Photo.class, name = "PhotoNote"),
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Document.class, name = "DocumentNote")
})
public abstract class Note implements Identifiable {
    [...]
```

Here is the Kotlin code I think would be equivalent:

```
JsonTypeInfo(
    use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
    include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY,
    property = "type")
JsonSubTypes(
    JsonSubTypes.Type(value = javaClass<Comment>(), name = "CommentNote"),
    JsonSubTypes.Type(value = javaClass<Photo>(), name = "PhotoNote"),
    JsonSubTypes.Type(value = javaClass<Document>(), name = "DocumentNote")
)
abstract class Note : Identifiable {
    [...]
```

But I get the following errors on each of the three "JsonSubTypes.Type" lines :

```
Kotlin: An annotation parameter must be a compile-time constant
Kotlin: Annotation class cannot be instantiated
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Turns out it's a [bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-6151) in the compiler, thanks for reporting it. To work around this issue, you can import `JsonSubTypes.Type` and use it without qualification:

```
import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonSubTypes.Type

JsonTypeInfo(
    use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
    include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY,
    property = "type")
JsonSubTypes(
    Type(value = javaClass<Comment>(), name = "CommentNote"),
    Type(value = javaClass<Photo>(), name = "PhotoNote"),
    Type(value = javaClass<Document>(), name = "DocumentNote")
)
abstract class Note : Identifiable {
    [...]
```

Answer (score 58):

I believe this has been resolved and nowadays you can write it like this:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonSubTypes
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeInfo

@JsonTypeInfo(
   use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
   include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY,
   property = "type")
   @JsonSubTypes(
       JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Comment::class, name = "CommentNote"),
       JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Photo::class, name = "PhotoNote"),
       JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Document::class, name = "DocumentNote"))
interface Note
```

Note the **missing @** and **class notation** in the `JsonSubTypes.Type`.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not able to check this anymore, but I still have a question.
Isn't `.java` property call required? e.g `value = Comment::class.java`

Comment: The compiler does not complain. It does when I use the .java property. This solution works in my project.

Answer (score 8):

I know this is an old question, nevertheless if someone is still searching for a solution to serialise/deserialise inherited classes in kotlin with jackson, I'd suggest using `sealed` classes and not using `@JsonSubTypes`.

I'd also suggest using `include` as `EXISTING_PROPERTY` and getting the property through a val inside the sealed class. Otherwise, if you add combined inherited objects inside an array, jackson won't be able to deserialise and will throw a `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidTypeIdException`.

Here is the example usage:

```kotlin
@JsonTypeInfo(
   use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
   include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXISTING_PROPERTY,
   property = "type")
sealed class Note{
    val type = this::class.java.simpleName
}
data class Document(val text: String, ...) : Note()
```

this should work like a charm, **including using this class inside an array!**

Another big advantage of this approach is, you don't need to set anything manually. As we all know, manual operations are error prone, as you can forget to add/remove/modify in case you add or remove a sub class, modify name etc. In this approach, you neither need to have a manually carved sub type list, nor need to give a json representation of the class name manually.

Comment: With this approach, how would you do if the name of the subclass does not match what the type would be in the JSON file?

Comment: you can't. basically that is the only relation between the subclass and the json

Comment: Ok. Then this answer seems rather incomplete, unfortunately :(

Comment: Sorry, I don't get why you think this is incomplete. If you have an example, it will be easier to discuss over.

Comment: Sorry, I meant that the person asking the question seemed to be having that requirement, since the class names are different than the field names. And I would guess that that's a quite common requirement.

Comment: if it is a requirement then it won't work, but i think in many situations it doesn't matter. it shouldn't be that different to have `Document` in json instead of `DocumentNote`.

Answer (score 2):

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXISTING_PROPERTY, property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes(
    JsonSubTypes.Type(Car::class, name = "car"),
    JsonSubTypes.Type(Truck::class, name = "truck")
)
abstract class Vehicle(val type: String)
data class Car @JsonCreator constructor(@JsonProperty("manufacturer") val manufacturer: String) : Vehicle("car")
data class Truck @JsonCreator constructor(@JsonProperty("weight") val weight: Double) : Vehicle("truck")

@Test
public fun jacksonInheritanceKt() {
    val s = "[{\"type\": \"car\", \"manufacturer\": \"audi\"}, {\"type\": \"truck\", \"weight\": 3000.0}]"

    val mapper = ObjectMapper()
    val vehicles = mapper.readValue(s, object : TypeReference<List<Vehicle>>() {})
    println(vehicles)
}
```