# Jackson deserialization to concrete polymorphic class

Tags: java, jackson, polymorphism

I have following Jackson annotated classes (Kotlin)

```
@JsonTypeInfo(
    use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
    include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY,
    property = "type"
)
@JsonSubTypes(
    value = [
        JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Child1::class, name = "child1"),
        JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Child2::class, name = "child2")
    ]
)
sealed class Parent 

class Child1: Parent()
class Child2: Parent()
```

I try to deserialize JSON that does not contain `type` property but I provide concrete class so it should not matter

```
// Kotlin extension method provides type in runtime
mapper.readValue<Child1>(json)
```

I get `Missing type id when trying to resolve subtype of ...` anyway. Is there a way how to tell Jackson to use the type provided in the deserialization and not to try find it from the `type` property?

Comment: Thanks, I have `Child2` in my code, this was a mistake caused by simplyfing the post. `readValue<Child1>` is Kotlin extension method which passes `Child1` as type parameter

Comment: Check this answer of another SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62444816/10668681

Comment: Check this answer in another SO question:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/62444816/10668681

Comment: Check this answer from another SO question:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/62444816/10668681

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There’s
 a [default implementation class to use for deserialization](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.11/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonTypeInfo.html#defaultImpl--) via `defaultImpl`:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, property = "type", defaultImpl = Child1.class)
```

From the Javadoc:

> Optional property that can be used to specify default implementation
>   class to use for deserialization if type identifier is either not
>   present, or can not be mapped to a registered type (which can occur
>   for ids, but not when specifying explicit class to use). Property has
>   no effect on choice of type id used for serialization; it is only used
>   in deciding what to do for otherwise unmappable cases.

Comment: Thanks, that solves part of the problem, what if I wanted to be able to deserialze both Childs?